# How to find elements in a 2 dimensional array with the biggest sum?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum, multidimensional-array, element

I need to find elements of an 2 dimensional array with maximal sum. Array have N rows and 13 columns, where MAXIMAL count of elements in a row is 4 and count of elements in a column MUST be 2. I tried use iteration through all combinations, but there is more combinations (10^27) than is Long.MAX_VALUE and when i tried recursion it caused stackoverflow.

Examples of possible solutions:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _             _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|X|X|X|X|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|M=4        |_|X|_|_|_|X|X|_|_|_|_|_|_| M=3
|X|X|X|X|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|M=4        |_|_|_|X|X|_|_|X|_|_|X|_|_| M=4
|_|_|_|_|X|X|X|X|_|_|_|_|_|M=4        |_|X|X|X|_|_|_|X|_|_|_|_|_| M=4
|_|_|_|_|X|X|X|X|_|_|_|_|_|M=4    or  |X|_|_|_|_|_|X|_|_|X|_|X|_| M=4
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|X|X|X|_|X|M=4        |_|_|_|_|X|_|_|_|X|X|_|_|_| M=4
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|X|X|X|X|_|M=4        |X|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|X|_|X|_|X| M=4
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|X|X|M=4        |_|_|X|_|_|X|_|_|_|_|_|_|_| M=3
                                      |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|X|X| M=2
```

M is maximal count of elemnts in first 6 columns and last 7 columns of the row.
I haven't any idea what to use to find them.

Comment: Is your problem finding the required row from an existing array, or are you unable to generate the array in the first place to begin with?

Comment: You can de-recurse you recursive algorithm using a stack.

Comment: I am not sure if I get it right what you actually want to do but the easiest way to find max sum in array is to sort all values descending by value (remember their original position somewhere or use indexed sort) and select first n-biggest values for the sum. no stack/recursion horriblness necessary.

Comment: My array is 
`int[][] h = {{502,511,0,517,521,0,518,521,507,461,420,556,433,4},{0,528,0,451,0 ,445,499,0,459,541,354,479,445, 4},{0,524,488,419,0,458,579,0,0,490,565,473,428, 4},{0,474,0,476,0,456,483,0,419,470,321,453,384,4}, {462,496,0,313,394,512,450,462,0,489,302,475,433,4},{314,412,316,315,398,413,401,352,0,402,320,391,318,4}, {353,312,0,255,0,322,321,355,0,346,215,345,250,4},` where each row means one swimmer and each column one discipline, except 14th, it's max count of disciplenes in first 6 columns and last 7 columns. Total max is 4 (I made a mistake above)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this as a [max flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

The idea is that flow represents an assignment from a swimmer to a discipline.

You can assign capacities in the flow problem in order to satisfy the constraints that each swimmer must do 2 disciplines, and each discipline can have at most 4 swimmers as shown in the  Python code below which uses the NetworkX library to solve the max flow problem.

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.DiGraph()

h = [[502,511,0,517,521,0,518,521,507,461,420,556,433,4],
     [0,528,0,451,0 ,445,499,0,459,541,354,479,445, 4],
     [0,524,488,419,0,458,579,0,0,490,565,473,428, 4],
     [0,474,0,476,0,456,483,0,419,470,321,453,384,4],
     [462,496,0,313,394,512,450,462,0,489,302,475,433,4],
     [314,412,316,315,398,413,401,352,0,402,320,391,318,4],
     [353,312,0,255,0,322,321,355,0,346,215,345,250,4]]

# Each row is a discipline
# Each swimmer must do two disciplines
# At most 4 swimmers in any one discipline

num_swimmers = len(h)
num_disciplines = len(h[0])

G.add_node('dest',demand=num_swimmers*2)
A=[]
for i,costs in enumerate(h):
    name='swimmer%d'%i
    A.append(name)
    G.add_node(name,demand=-2) # 2 units of flow start at each swimmer 
    for discipline,cost in enumerate(costs):
        d='discipline%d'%discipline
        G.add_edge(name,d,capacity=1,weight=-cost)
for discipline in range(num_disciplines):
    d='discipline%d'%discipline
    G.add_edge(d,'dest',capacity=4,weight=0) # Can have at most 4 swimmers per discipline

flowdict = nx.min_cost_flow(G)
for swimmer in A:
    for d,flow in flowdict[swimmer].items():
        if flow:
            print swimmer,'->',d

print 'Total cost =',-nx.cost_of_flow(G,flowdict)
```

This prints the answer:

```
swimmer0 -> discipline4
swimmer0 -> discipline11
swimmer1 -> discipline1
swimmer1 -> discipline9
swimmer2 -> discipline6
swimmer2 -> discipline10
swimmer3 -> discipline6
swimmer3 -> discipline3
swimmer4 -> discipline5
swimmer4 -> discipline1
swimmer5 -> discipline5
swimmer5 -> discipline1
swimmer6 -> discipline7
swimmer6 -> discipline0
Total cost = 6790
```